# BitmapFactory.Options outHeight and outWidth returning -1 for large images

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to resize a large image. For small images this code works properly, however for large images outHeight and outWidth are always -1, creating a NullPointerException. This is particularly odd since I set options.inJustDecodeBounds = true, which should prevent this kind of error since memory usage is reduced. Am I missing something? My methods are below:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "FileNotFoundException");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "IOException");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, IMAGE_SIZE,
                    IMAGE_SIZE);
            InputStream inputStreamTwo = null;
            try {
                inputStreamTwo = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "FileNotFoundException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap unscaledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreamTwo,
                    null, options);
            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledImage, IMAGE_SIZE,
                    IMAGE_SIZE, false);
            Log.d("Unscaled image byte count",
                    "Bytes: " + unscaledImage.getByteCount());
            Log.d("Scaled image byte count", "Bytes: " + image.getByteCount());
        }
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Update: This happens on small images too (around 100KB) which are JPGs. It does not happen for larger JPGs (1.2MB) taken by the phone's camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the images were from Picasa, so they weren't stored on the SD, creating a NullPointerException. You can set intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true) before launching the activity to restrict items in the Gallery only to those on the SD card. I'll post a better solution if I find one.